# Getting "/dev/log" in the "gcloud app logs tail" stream

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud, google-cloud-logging

In the browser cloud console for my Google App Engine app, I can choose to see the logs for `/dev/log` and `stderr` which gives me all of the log entries that I'm expecting to see.

However, when I use the command line `gcloud app logs tail` to stream the logs in my terminal, I can't get it to give me the `/dev/log` entries.

The docs say the default list of logs include: `stderr,stdout,crash.log,nginx.request,request_log`

So the `/dev/log` must be represented by some other identifier, but I can't find any docs on what it might be. I've tried a few guesses, but none work.

How can I can the terminal to stream the same logs I'm getting in my browser?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use command like [gcloud logging read](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/logging/read) to interact with Stackdriver logging & get a non streamed version of those logs. Setup the Stackdriver GUI with the logs you wish to see, then convert to an [advanced filter](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-filters). You can then paste the advanced filter as is, in quotations after gcloud logging read. Examples in gcloud logging read documentation. I will get back to you in a comment on this post as to whether you can get the /dev/log logs with the gcloud app logs tail command. I will update on Saturday